# Calling method based on json object parameter in Spark scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions, scala-collections

I have JSON object like below..

```
{"name":"method1","parameter1":"P1","parameter2":"P2","parameter3":"P3","parameter4":"P4"}

{"name":"method2","parameter1":"P1","parameter2":"P2","parameter3":"P3","parameter4":"P4","parameter5":"P5","parameter6":"P6"}
```

I have different function with different logic like bellow

```
def method1(P1:String, P2:Int, P3:String, P4:String)={
  println(p1)
  println(p2)
  println(p3)
  println(p4)
} 

def method2(P1:String, P2:Int, P3:String, P4:String,P5:String,P6:String)={
  println(p1)
  println(p2)
  println(p3)
  println(p4)
  println(p6)
  println(p5)
}
```

Using this object I have to call my method.

For example, my JSON object contain first parameter method1, then I have to call the first function ( like `method1(P1: String, P2: Int, P3: String, P4: String)` )  with reaming properties as a parameter.

Based on my JSON first parameter I have called this function with remaining parameters. 
Please let me know how can I achieve this?

Comment: your method2 contains only four parameters as arguments. where are you getting p5 and p6 from? And clarify what do you want to achieve with those functions as well.

Comment: I just want to call methods based on my json object.if first json object contain first parameter method1 then it should call first method with remaining parameter.

Comment: Look for an `eval` like method in Scala and a way to parse the JSON. Anyway, it's going to be dirty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the solution using `dataframe`.

You have a valid `json` format that can be read through *spark* into a `dataframe`

```
val df = sqlContext.read.json("path to the json file")
```

which should be give you `dataframe` as

```
+-------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|name   |parameter1|parameter2|parameter3|parameter4|parameter5|parameter6|
+-------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|method1|P1        |P2        |P3        |P4        |null      |null      |
|method2|P1        |P2        |P3        |P4        |P5        |P6        |
+-------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Now I have modified your two functions by changing *primitive datatypes* to `column` and *printing* is changed to *concatenation* of strings passed.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
def method1(P1:Column, P2:Column, P3:Column, P4:Column)={
  concat_ws(",", P1, P2, P3, P4)
}

def method2(P1:Column, P2:Column, P3:Column, P4:Column,P5:Column,P6:Column)={
  concat_ws(",", P1, P2, P3, P4, P5, P6)
}
```

You can call those two methods depending on the value populated on `name` column using `when` function as below

```
df.withColumn("methodCalling", when($"name" === "method1", method1($"parameter1",$"parameter2",$"parameter3",$"parameter4"))
  .otherwise(when($"name" === "method2", method2($"parameter1",$"parameter2",$"parameter3",$"parameter4",$"parameter5",$"parameter6"))))
  .show(false)
```

which should give you

```
+-------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+-----------------+
|name   |parameter1|parameter2|parameter3|parameter4|parameter5|parameter6|methodCalling    |
+-------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+-----------------+
|method1|P1        |P2        |P3        |P4        |null      |null      |P1,P2,P3,P4      |
|method2|P1        |P2        |P3        |P4        |P5        |P6        |P1,P2,P3,P4,P5,P6|
+-------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+-----------------+
```

I hope the answer is helpful and should give you more than general idea of how you should proceed.

Comment: same above your code i am executing , my input json {"name":"method1","parameter1":"C:/Users/test/Desktop/test.csv","parameter2":1.0,"parameter3":"C:/Users/test/Desktop/output"} with required method parameters and df.withColumn("methodCalling", when($"name" === "method1", method1($"parameter1",$"parameter2",$"parameter3")).otherwise(when($"name" === "method2", method2($"parameter1",$"parameter2")))).show(false) i am getting error like "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class scala.runtime.BoxedUnit ()" please help me on this

Comment: @saikumar,did you use the method1 and method2 as i have mentioned in my answer?

Comment: I used method1 with above comment json i am getting error,if i use your code in with above  json objects (question),  method1 and method2, it is as per your answer.

Comment: my answer has four parameters in method1 and six parameters in method2 but when you called it from within when function you are passing only three parameters and when you called method2 you are passing only two parameters. how is that possible? Think about it yourself.

Comment: i have changed function like 3 and  2 parameters.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159373/discussion-between-ramesh-maharjan-and-sai-kumar).